# Cannot open settings on ubuntu 23.10 GNOME

Tags: gnome, gnome-control-center, 23.10

After upgrading from Ubuntu 23.04 to Ubuntu 23.10 I can't open settings.
I was trying to open settings via terminal using

> gnome-control-center

but I got message:

> Running gnome-control-center is only supported under GNOME and Unity, exiting

but the problem is I am using GNOME...

I was experimenting with KDE plasma earlier but now I'm clearly using GNOME.

> echo $DESKTOP_SESSION

says just "ubuntu"

edit:
running

> export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP='ubuntu:GNOME'

in terminal allowed me to open settings from that terminal

Comment: What does `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` say?

Comment: also just "ubuntu"

Comment: It says "ubuntu:GNOME" on my system though.

Comment: I tried 
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP='ubuntu:GNOME'
and it temporarily worked. I can open gnome-control-center from that terminal but only from there